# Create dataframe with values from other dataframe's indices and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe `df1` that looks like:

```
    0     1     2

0   NaN   1     5
1   0.5   NaN   1
2   1.25  3     NaN
```

And I want to create another dataframe `df2` with three columns where the values for the first two columns correspond to the `df1` columns and indices, and the third column is the cell value.

So `df2` would look like:

```
   src   dst    cost 

0   0     1     0.5
1   0     2     1.25
2   1     0     5
3   1     2     3
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's probably a clever way to do this with [`pd.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html) or [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) but this works:

```py
df2 = (
    # reorganize the data to be row-wise with a multi-index
    df1.stack()
    # drop missing values
    .dropna()
    # name the axes
    .rename_axis(['src', 'dst'])
    # name the values
    .to_frame('cost')
    # return src and dst to columns
    .reset_index(drop=False)
)
```